# ColdFusion to access secure web service

Tags: web-services, coldfusion

I am trying to access a secure web service using cfhttp tag in CFML but I am getting the following error:

"Could not establish the trust relationship for the SSL/TSL secure channel."

Can anyone please help??

Answer (score 8):

Is the SSL cert is self-signed you will need to download it and install it in CF's keystore:

1. In IE go to a page where the cert is available.
2. Click on the lock icon next to the URL location
3. Select “View Certificates”
4. Click the “Details” tab
5. Click the “Copy to File” button
6. In step 2 of the wizard select the “Base-64 encoded x.509 (.cer)” option.
7. In step 3 find the location of your security folder. This should be in /ColdFusion8/runtime/jre/lib/security/
   Save the cert with a name of your choosing
8. Inside the JRE/bin you will find a application called keytool.exe which can import this
   cert. Execute the following command replacing “MyCert” with the name you gave
   the cert:
   a. keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -
   alias mycert -file mycert.cer
9. You should receive a message that “Certificate was added to keystore”

For more information on the Java Keytool see:
http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/keytool.html